# Laravel 4: Whoops library and set_cookie function

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I updated to the latest version of Laravel 4 using composer update. Now I'm having a problem with the error handling library it uses - Whoops. When I have an error in my code, for instance an syntax error the following happens:

1. I reload the page
2. The actual exception ('Unexpected xxxx at ...') appears for less than a second
3. Another exception replaces it:

   ```
   Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/planewalker/Sites/jean/welper/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Run.php:204)
   ```

The code at the above line is this:

```
        // If we're allowed to, send output generated by handlers directly
        // to the output, otherwise, return it so that it may be used by
        // the caller.
        if($this->writeToOutput()) {
            echo $output;
        }

        return $output;
```

and more specifically the `echo $output;` part.

Does anyone know why this happens?

UPDATE:

I've now determined that the problem is caused by the set_cookie function in combination with the Whoops library's exception output. It seems that the set_cookie function is called after the Whoops library has started outputting its view.

The only solution I found was to use a different session driver that the 'cookie' one. I've switched to using 'native' and the problem does not appear anymore.

Comment: A fix has [just been pushed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/24eaef231e0e3e903cbbe7a80a1a4fa7af032294) that sounds like it'll solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, Jason! You are correct - this addresses the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you edited the `start.php` or `path.php` for echoing debug informations. In the most cases this is the problem.
Because start.php is called before the errorhandler is called and in Laravel for every output headers are sent.

Comment: No, I haven't edited them. What I did is just composer update. I wasn't experiencing the problem before the update and haven't changed any files that may have cause the problem.

Comment: Thats strange. Try running `composer dump-autoload' and 'php artisan optimize'.

Comment: Just did that without any result. The problem still persists: I see the exception I'm looking for for a second and then it's replaced by the other one. As if the Whoops page is loaded once and then again on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Laravel 4:

```
composer update
```

This problem should be fixed and you would receive the first exception which is thrown.